# Android Navigation Drawer Remains Highlighted

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-drawer

I am able to navigate from Activity1 to Activity2 via my navigation drawer.

But upon pressing the back button at activity2, the option remains highlighted.

My Code in activity1 is as followed

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem Item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.activity2)
    {
        Intent goPage2 = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
        startActivity(goPage2);
    }
}
```

there is no code in activity 2.

May I know what do I do to remove the highlight?

Comment: what do u mean by **option remains highlighted**. ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCfTs.png

Comment: this is an image i found online which matches my case.

Comment: check out the answer i posted now,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To uncheck the item click, you must pass `false` on checked item:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem Item) //will consider to keep this in lower case - item
{
int id = item.getItemId();

 if(id == R.id.activity2)
 {
    Intent goPage2 = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
    startActivity(goPage2);
    Item.setChecked(false);  //pass false to uncheck
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been reading so many complicated solution and i didn't know mine was so simple. Thanks!!

Comment: Cool man, one more thing change the `Item` to `item` on `MenuItem Item` .

Comment: Noted, i'll change, the "item" was generated by android studio itself, but i shall change it now!

Answer (score 11):

I have found that simply return false, at the end of onNavigationItemSelected,   if you have no need to use the highlight feature.

```
       } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. The actual accepted one doesn't dehighlight at all.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will remain highlighted("selected" more professional) because when you select an item from `Navigation Drawer` next activity is created and the activity in which the `Navigation Drawer` exists gets paused and stopped not destroyed (`onPause()`then `onStop()` are called) and remains in the memory till your device has enough memory. So, going to next activity does not consume much memory to force android to destroy previous activity. What you can do is either destroy your Navigation Drawer activity completely or you can uncheck all the items in the Navigation Drawer manually by writing this code for all items in `onRestart()` method of first activity.

```
menuItem1.setChecked(false);
menuItem2.setChecked(false);
menuItem3.setChecked(false);
menuItem4.setChecked(false);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `menuItem.setChecked(true)` should check it and `menuItem.setChecked(false)` to uncheck it.